# overflow:hidden not removing horizontal scrollbar from jQuery cycle in IE

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer, yii, blueprint-css

I am using jQuery.cycle to show three images. Keeping with other answers on this site, I used a combination of `min-width` and `overflow:hidden` to remove the horizontal scrollbar, which only appears in Internet Exploder Nein.

In case it's relevant, the site uses both the Yii framework and Blueprint.

The horizontal scrollbar is not going away. Why?

**Action**

```
<?php
class IndexAction extends CAction
{
    public function run()
    {
        $ds = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
        $cs = Yii::app()->clientScript;

        $cs->registerScriptFile( $ds. 'js' . $ds .
                  'jquery.cycle.all.js', CClientScript::POS_HEAD );

        $cs->registerScript( 'cycle', "$('.pics').cycle({
            fx: 'scrollLeft',
            containerResize: false,
            slideResize: false,
            width:960,
            height:300,
            fit:true
        });", CClientScript::POS_END );

        $this->controller->render('index');
    }
}
```

**View**

```
<?php
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCss('ServicesCycleSlideShow',"
.pics {  
    min-width:960px;  
    height:300px;  
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    overflow:hidden;
} 

.pics img {  
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border:  none;  
    min-width:  960px; 
    height: 300px; 
    overflow:hidden;
}");
?>
<div class="pics"> 
    <img src="/images/1.png" width="960" height="300" /> 
    <img src="/images/2.png" width="960" height="300" /> 
    <img src="/images/3.png" width="960" height="300" /> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem. jQuery.cycle introduces `overflow-x:scroll`, which took precedence over `overflow:hidden`. Adding `overflow-x:hidden` removes the scrollbar.